# Finding the samallest yellow rectangle

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I have implemented the following methods in `1` and `2` and need feedback to improve my implementation. Any different approach and ideas are welcome.

> 1. A static method, minRectangle, accepts an array of rectangles (objects of type Rectangle) and returns the rectangle with the smallest area. Create this method.
> 2. A static method, selectRectangles, accepts an array of rectangles (objects of type Rectangle) and a color (an object of type String), and returns those rectangles (as an array) that are of the given color. Create this method.
> 3. Create an array of rectangles (objects of type Rectangle). Then use the methods selectRectangles and minRectangle to determine the smallest of the rectangles in the array that are yellow.

```
public class Rectangle {

// the lengths of the rectangle’s sides
private double length;
private double width;

// the rectangle’s color
private String color;

public Rectangle(double length, double width, String color) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.color = color;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public double area() {
    return length * width;

}

public String toString() {
    return "<" + this.length + ", " + this.width + "," + this.color + ">";

}

public static Rectangle minRectangle(Rectangle[] rect) {

    Rectangle min = rect[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
        if (rect[i].area() < min.area()) {
            min = rect[i];
        }
    }
    return min;

}

public static Rectangle[] selectRectangles(Rectangle[] rect, String color) {
    int countRect = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
        if (rect[i].getColor().equals(color))
            countRect++;

    }

    Rectangle[] Rect = new Rectangle[countRect];
    int companionVar = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < rect.length; j++) {
        if(rect[j].getColor().equals(color))
        Rect[companionVar++] = rect[j];


    }
    return Rect;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle[] rect = {new Rectangle(2, 3, "yellow"),
            new Rectangle(3, 5, "red"),
            new Rectangle(1, 1, "yellow"),
            new Rectangle(2, 2, "red"),
            new Rectangle(3, 4, "red"),
            new Rectangle(2, 8, "red"),
            new Rectangle(5, 2, "yellow")};

    System.out.println("Smallest yellow Rectangle:" + minRectangle(rect));
    Rectangle[] rectangles = selectRectangles(rect, "yellow");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rectangles));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `minRectangle` is doing what it should but could be improved by storing the value of `area()` in a variable. Assume you have 1.000.000 rectangles to check then the calculation would happen 2.000.000 times.

```
public static Rectangle minRectangle(Rectangle[] rect) {

    Rectangle min = rect[0];
    double minArea = min.area();

    for (int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
        double currentArea = rect[i].area();
        if (currentArea < minArea) {
            min = rect[i];
            minArea = currentArea; 
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

---

The selectRectangles() method is doing too much work as well. By using an `List<Rectangle>` to add the rectangles with the desired color and returning the list as array will speed this up.

Please don't omit braces `{}` although they might be optional. Omitting braces can lead to hidden and therfor hard to track bugs.

```
public static Rectangle[] selectRectangles(Rectangle[] rect, String color) {
    List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
    int countRect = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
        if (rect[i].getColor().equals(color)) {
            rectangles.add(rect[i]);
        }
    }

    Rectangle[] results = new Rectangle[rectangles.size()];

    return rectangles.toArray(results);
}
```

---

The last task in question isn't solved correctly. You should first get the yellow rectangles in the array and then detect the smallest of these.

Answer (score 2):

#### `private` variables

As suggested by [@Heslacher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/159436/24141), you can store the `area` as a `private` variable as well to avoid having to re-calculate each time `area()` is called. Do be careful about overflow, so you may want to use something like `BigDecimal` for that:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private final double length;
    private final double width;
    private final String color;
    private final BigDecimal area;

    public Rectangle(double length, double width, String color) {
        if (!Double.isFinite(length) || !Double.isFinite(width) || color == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "Length, width or color defined incorrectly.");
        }
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.color = color;
        this.area = BigDecimal.valueOf(length).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(width));
    }
}
```

This performs some basic validation on the constructor's parameters too.

#### Java 8

Maybe you are restricted by the programming challenge rules, but it's good to know how much simpler Java 8 can make it:

```
public static Rectangle getSmallest(String color, Rectangle... rectangles) {
    return Arrays.stream(rectangles)
                .filter(r -> r.getColor().equals(color))
                .min(Comparator.comparing(Rectangle::area))
                .orElse(null); // return null if none found (unlikely?)
}
```

I have rearranged the parameters so that the `Rectangle` array can alternatively be passed in as the `varargs` form.

Here, we call on the [`Stream.min(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) method to perform the comparison for us, and the `Comparator` is constructed by using [`Comparator.comparing(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with `Rectangle::area` as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

***I also think question (3) is expecting a `Rectangle` to be returned as the result, not a `Rectangle[]` array.***